# I have installed Ubuntu 12.04, now my Windows Vista doesn't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-vista

I have a Windows Vista computer. And I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it. But now, when I boot my device it doesn't ask me which OS I want to choose, instead it just boots in Ubuntu. Please help me! I don't know what to do... :/

P.S.: I've created a partition with the Ubuntu installer. My hard disk drive is 250 gb (there around) and the partition is 30gb big...

P.S.S.: It's very important because is my mom's computer and there are some very important files on it... :(

Comment: All this is good, but is there a way to save my files other than taking a hard drive out and putting it into another computer and copy them on another computer?

Comment: Actually,if your Windows files are not encrypted, you can acess them directly from Ubuntu and save them to a external drive for example. You just have to go to your home folder and look for your Windows Partition on the left panel (something like Local Disk) Then you can navigate inside your Windows folders.

Comment: I think they are, becouse I dont see my windows partition... :(

Comment: Hum, are you sure? Because encryption on Windows is an additional feature, not by default on basic versions. Well, go to your home folder and tell me what do you see on the left panel (you can also take a screenshot, upload it to skydrive or dropbox or ubuntu one and paste a public link here, if you have an account on one of those services), so I can see if Windows partition is there.

Comment: Anyway, it won't take much more than 10 minutes to fix this issue using the solutions present on the link I pasted on my answer. I strongly recommend that you do it and fix your boot, so you can use Ubuntu and Windows together without any trouble.

Comment: My dad curently trying to fix grub with a third party programs... so I guess I will write about my/my dad's sucess. But remember that it is not the computer what me and my dad are rescuing, but the data wich is a lot more inportant than the computer and is also a lot more valuable than the computer...

Comment: Please run boot info script http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces. Also, please be careful when trying to fix things, I've seen people start with easy to fix (once you know how) problems and make the situation *much* worse by trying random "fixes". Don't try a "solution" until you're sure that you understand the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Boot Repair, which is a GRUB repairing tool for Ubuntu. It may help you to fix any possible problem with Ubuntu's boot.

The app's main menu looks like this:

[image: Boot Repair]

For install it:

1. Open a terminal, searching the app in the Dash.
2. Copy & paste this: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
3. Follow the instructions.
4. Now copy and paste `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
5. Follow instructions again.
6. When installed, open Boot Repair from the Dash. Click now on *Recommended Repair*.
7. When done, note the URL which appears on the screen. Reply me with the URL if you still have problems.

More info about the app here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Boot loader. Try `boot-repair`.
More info about the app here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well.

Here it is the fix that solved this problem for me:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bootinfoscript/index.php?title=Boot_Problems:Boot_Sector